# How uncomfortable are old Paris apartments with no AC in July heat?

Tags: accommodation, paris, weather-and-climate

I have never lived without an AC and I get quite ill if I get hot. I'm curious how hot old Paris spaces get in July with no AC? Thinking of renting a space on the fifth floor of an old building in the 9th.

Comment: Have you looked at the [climate diagram of Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Paris#Climate)? This will of course depend on where are you from, but it doesn't actually get very hot most of the times in Paris.

Comment: Yes but the building materials and the construction make a difference. Curious how bad it gets if it's 25 outside how crap is it inside?

Comment: Is that 5th floor a converted attic?

Comment: @JoE Not certain and I don't want to ask because the guy is already irritated I asked "too many" questions such as is there AC or a handheld shower. lol

Comment: @verve You might want to push a bit more since that's a very important piece of information: converted attics are poorly insulated meaning that you freeze in the winter and bake in the summer.

Comment: In a Hausmann building, the 5th floor would usually be the highest “proper” floor. There is another one top, not necessarily “converted” per se but always less comfortable as it was originally intended for servants.

Comment: If your host is not willing to answer basic questions, it might be better to find one who is.

Comment: @Max  Yes, I know but I can't afford anybody else. Lol.

Comment: @Relaxed Interesting.  It must be old. He said you need to use a brass key to get to the place. Toxic that brass. Sigh.

Comment: Where do you live now? What climates are you used to?

Answer (score 4):

Some days will be quite hot in Paris in July, and if you're used to living with AC it will be an adjustment. I stayed in Paris for a month last July and had to get used to sleeping with a single light sheet, moving as little as possible, and waking up sweaty. Old buildings will likely have poor ventilation, to compound the matter.

Comment: Yet many people live in non-AC houses and survive. But the trek from Paris to the countryside in August may have its roots in the weather and lack of ventilation.

Comment: Sweaty sucks since I don't want to shower every morning but before bed.